# How to get the field (' ID ') in a fdQuery based on the item clicked in a listview (Delphi)

Tags: listview, delphi, firedac

I have an FMX app I am working on.

I have a ListView binded to a table in an Sqlite database.

[image]

Of course, all works great, and loads all the drinks in the ListView.

[image]

When I click on a drink item in the ListView, the binded fields show correctly.

[image]

So, here is the question.

How can I get the `idDrink` field binded to the clicked ListView item?

I need to do this so I can concatenate all the ingredient fields and add them to a Memo.

I like the Visual Bindings, but some things have to be done in code.

This is what I have so far:

```
procedure TForm2.lvDrinksListviewItemClick(const Sender: TObject;
const AItem: TListViewItem);
var

  idDrink: string;
  strDrinks: string;
  listviewindex: string;
  instructions: String;
  ingredients: String;
begin
  qryDrinks.SQL.Text := 'select * From drinks ';
  qryDrinks.Open();
  listviewindex := (TListViewItem(lvDrinksListview.Selected).Text);
  idDrink := qryDrinks.Fields[0].AsString;
  TListViewItem(lvDrinksListview.Selected).Text := listviewindex ;  /// Here i need to set the idDrink to := the listview selected item
  instructions := qryDrinks.Fields[9].AsString;
  ingredients := qryDrinks.Fields[17].AsString + sLineBreak + qryDrinks.Fields
    [18].AsString + #13 + qryDrinks.Fields[19].AsString;
  showmessage(idDrink);
  showmessage((listviewindex));
  Memo4.Lines.Add(ingredients);
  qryDrinks.Next;
  qryDrinks.Close();

  TabControl1.ActiveTab := tiDrinksIngreediantsAndDirections;
end;
```

Comment: Why are bringing up this question on StackOverflow when you have already been [getting help on Delphi Praxis](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/10010-get-iddrink-out-of-database-based-on-what-is-clicked-in-listbox/) for almost a week now?

Comment: Why do you have separate fields for separate ingredients? You should learn about relational database connections and restructure your database accordingly. Once you set up proper relational connections retrieving ingredients could be dne using s simple SQL query which can also join them into a single string. You could then even use reverse query where you specify which ingredients you have available and get all the possible drinks you can make with those ingredients as a result. In the same way you could get rid of multiple fields for instructions in multiple languages that you also have now.

Comment: You still use a bad structure database ! As I show you on Delphi Praxis (I supply also a zip with source and database) the way is to have different tables (at least 2 : Cocktails and Ingredients, Ingredients as detail of the Cocktails one).

Comment: P.S. " I get the idDrink field" is tbldrinksIDDrink.value

Comment: Hey thanks for the comments. I do have this working with a different database with tables for the drinks and ingredients, . Im just wording how to get the data out of the same table . I think it sould be possible.

Comment: I posted here for a different perspective . I was wondering if someone here may have done this kind of thing. I did not mean to step on anyone's toes :)  Thanks to all who help at delphipraxis. Thanks again for all comment.

Comment: " I'm just wording how to get the data out of the same table. I think it should be possible."
It is, but a nonsense when you use a relational database. 
as I said : 2 ways 
- working on the DataSet 
changing FDTable to FDquery and use concatanation
SELECT  idDrink,strDrink,instructions||IIF(stringedient1 IS NULL,'',x'0A'||stringredient1)||IIF(stringedient2 IS NULL,'',x'0A'||stringredient2)...   as instructionsAndValue
or 
add a Calculate Dataset Field and concatenate in the OnCalcField event

- Create a Binding method